# AWS Control Tower failed to set up your landing zone completely: ... because the log group already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-control-tower, aws-landing-zone

I am trying to setup a new landing zone with the AWS Control Tower but I get stuck at the same step even after multiple attempts.

> AWS Control Tower failed to set up your landing zone completely: AWS
> Control Tower cannot create log group
> /aws/lambda/aws-controltower-NotificationForwarder because the log
> group already exists. To continue, delete the log group from Amazon
> CloudWatch and try again.

The things is that there is no log group with that name. I have no issues manually creating a log group with the same name nor deleting it afterwards.

I am not quite sure how to continue troubleshooting. The stack setting up another CloudWatch log group works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check of the CoudWatch loggroup in all the 5 regions - N Virginia, Ohio, Oregon, Sydney and Ireland in the master account

Comment: Thank you for your message.
It turned out that there was some log groups in the accounts that Control Tower created. Once I removed the log group from those accounts I could complete the setup.